# pushing object into array schema in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this mongoose schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var ContactSchema = module.exports = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  phone: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    index: {unique: true}
  },
  messages: [
  {
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    msg: {type: String, required: true}
  }]
}, {
    collection: 'contacts',
    safe: true
});
```

and trying to update the model by doing this:

```
Contact.findById(id, function(err, info) {
    if (err) return res.send("contact create error: " + err);

    // add the message to the contacts messages
    Contact.update({_id: info._id}, {$push: {"messages": {title: title, msg: msg}}}, function(err, numAffected, rawResponse) {
      if (err) return res.send("contact addMsg error: " + err);
      console.log('The number of updated documents was %d', numAffected);
      console.log('The raw response from Mongo was ', rawResponse);

    });
  });
```

I'm I not declaring the `messages` to take an array of objects?
**ERROR:** MongoError: Cannot apply $push/$pushAll modifier to non-array

Any ideas?

Comment: What error message are you getting?  What do you mean by "I can't seem to get the `$push` done right"?

Comment: MongoError: Cannot apply $push/$pushAll modifier to non-array

Comment: Not sure if this will fix it, but try taking away the square brackets from around `[{title: title, msgs: [msg]}]`.  `$push` takes in a single value.

Comment: no dice... same error

Comment: Is the `messages` schema an array?  I'm putting brackets around it so wouldn't mongoose pick that up?  So then when I `$push` is should work?

Comment: How are you registering the schema with mongoose?

Comment: var ContactSchema = module.exports = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  phone: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    index: {unique: true}
  },
  messages: [
  {
    title: String,
    msg: String
  }]
}, {
    collection: 'contacts',
    safe: true
});

Comment: Try with quotation marks around 'messages' in the update

Comment: no dice... same error

Comment: Try running a find() on the collection and printing a document from it

Comment: {
        "__v" : 0,
        "_id" : ObjectId("515071f5766dc5fc05000002"),
        "messages" : {
                "title" : "GoodNight",
                "msg" : "sleeping beauty",
                "_id" : ObjectId("51509ea3981fca2014000003")
        },
        "name" : "belatirx",
        "phone" : 6578201987
}  for some reason it does not come out as an array even though the schema is, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's weird... how are you initially creating the document with the messages array?

Comment: I got it working.  restarted the application and now its working.  Not sure how/why.  thanks

Comment: My guess is you are initially adding the messages as a non-array

Comment: @user1460015 Please mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 127):

mongoose does this for you in one operation.

```
Contact.findByIdAndUpdate(
    info._id,
    {$push: {"messages": {title: title, msg: msg}}},
    {safe: true, upsert: true},
    function(err, model) {
        console.log(err);
    }
);
```

Please keep in mind that using this method, you will not be able to make use of the schema's "pre" functions.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

As of the latest mogoose findbyidandupdate needs to have a "new : true" optional param added to it. Otherwise you will get the old doc returned to you. Hence the update for Mongoose Version 4.x.x converts to :

```
Contact.findByIdAndUpdate(
        info._id,
        {$push: {"messages": {title: title, msg: msg}}},
        {safe: true, upsert: true, new : true},
        function(err, model) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    );
```

Comment: @TejasManohar its just to show that you can have multiple options included there.

Comment: this answer helped me a lot. But what's with those options, `safe`, `upsert` and `new`?

Comment: "new" - so that you get the updated document in return (read answer description)

"upsert" - Optional. If set to true, creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria. The default value is false, which does not insert a new document when no match is found.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

"safe" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974686/mongodb-should-i-always-use-the-safe-option-on-updates

Comment: Thanks for a real answer :)

Comment: what's `info._id`, is it a string or an ObjectId ?

Comment: @bubakazouba ObjectIds are strings

Comment: Method becomes undefined when references a custom method on the object.

Comment: `safe` is not included in the documentation for `.findOneAndUpdate()`

Comment: What is the purpose of `safe: true` and `upsert: true`. I have seen it in lots of answers but dont really know the meaning of it

Answer (score 8):

there are two ways for pushing data in array

first way:

```
let newMessage = {title: "new title", msg: "new Message"}
let result = await Contact.findById(id);
result.messages.push(newMessage);
await result.save();
```

second way

```
let result = await Contact.findByIdAndUpdate(
        id,
        {$push: {"messages": {title: title, msg: msg}}},
        {upsert: true, new : true})
```