# Insert new values in array in mongoose

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose

Below code contains two schema now  Grocery Schema contains array of users in which i want to store all users id which are related to itemName
I have no clue  how to insert  new values in  mongodb

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var GrocerySchema= new Schema({
itemName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
completed: Boolean,
  date: String,
 users:[{user_id:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:user}}]
});

grocerydata=mongoose.model('grocery',GrocerySchema);
var UserSchema = new Schema({

      fname: {
       type:String,
       required:true
       },
     lname:{type:String},

     email: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
     }
});
 module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I have used below code for saving the multiple values and set the value of array

```
    var docs=    {
    itemName : req.body.item,
    completed: true,
    date: new Date(),
    $push: {"users": {user_id: req.body._id}}
    }

    }

     grocerydata.create(docs, function(err, results) {
      if (err)
        res.send(err);
      console.log(results);
   });
```

but I am not able to push the user_id in  Grocery Please help me 
Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your last snippet of code. `var docs` should be the following:

```
var docs={
  itemName : req.body.item,
  completed: true,
  date: new Date(),
  //you forgot to wrap $push in {}
  {$push: {"users": {user_id: req.body._id}}}
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621970/pushing-object-into-array-schema-in-mongoose)