# How to save array to monggodb

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

iwant to save this array to mongodb this is mycode

```
<% if(soal.length){

        for(var i = 0;i < soal.length;i++) { %>

    <tr>

        <td><%=(i+1)%><input type="hidden" value="<%=soal[i]._id%>" name="soal[i]">
            <p  name="soal" value="<%=soal[i].soal%>" >Soal: <%=soal[i].soal%></p></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <input type="radio" name="jawaban[<%=i%>]>" valeu="A"><label>A</label>
            <%=soal[i].jawabana%> </input> <br>

            <input type="radio" name="jawaban[<%=i%>]" valeu="B"><label>B</label>
            <%=soal[i].jawabanb%></input> <br>


        </td>

    </tr>

    <% }

    }%>
```

and this is my model for mongodb

```
var Hasilujian = new mongoose.Schema({
nis: String,
soal :[{type: String}],
jawaban : [{type: String}]
```

});

i cant save to mongodb anyone to help me about my project

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621970/pushing-object-into-array-schema-in-mongoose

Comment: where is your code to insert/save?

Comment: exports.saveujian = function(req, res) {
 if (req.session.Siswa){
     Siswa.find({nis : req.session.Siswa.username},function(err, siswa){
        var nis_siswa = req.session.Siswa.nis;
         var sol = req.body.soal;

 var dat = new Hasilujian({
    nis : nis_siswa,
    soal : sol.soal,
    jawaban : sol.jawaban
});
         dat.save(function(err){
        if(err) res.json(err);
        else{
            res.redirect('/Ujian')
        }
    })
     });
 }else res.redirect('/');

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it in simple manner.

The array in model can be registered as

```
  purchased_items: [{

  }]
```

or little bit modified :

```
 purchased_items: [{
    product : String,
    quantity : Number,
    date :  {
      type :Date,
      default : Date.now
    }
  }]
```

let me know if its work.

Happy coding!