# Connect mongoose-array-values to a unique ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This may seem like a vague question, but I'm going to try to explain the best I can. As a side note, I'm quite new to using mongoose :)

I have a mongoose-schema storing different values for each user, like so...

```
let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    pass: { type: String, required: true },
    files: [{ type: String, required: false }],
});
```

The "files"-key contains an array of values, lets say for example:

```
userSchema.files = [value1, value2, value3]
```

And I want each value to be connected to some kind of ID, so that when I call the specified ID, I get the specified value. Just for demonstrating purposes, it could look something like this:

```
userSchema.files = [{value:value1, id: id1}, 
                    {value:value2, id: id2}, 
                    {value:value3, id: id3}]
```

Then I want to find the specified id, and return it's "value"-key in a request:

```
router.route("/home/:id")
    .get(restrict, function(req, res) {

        User.findOne({ user: req.session.Auth.username }, function(error, data) {
            data.files.forEach(function(file) {
               if (file.id === req.params.id) {
               response.render("../home", file.value)
               }
            }
        });
    });
```

How can I do this? Tried pushing an object to files, but that didn't work as expected. Read something about ObjectId, but couldn't quite understand it. **Any tips?**

Comment: Are you getting `data` correctly? Are you facing problem with inserting or retrieving?

Comment: @RaR I'm facing problems with inserting!

Comment: What have you tried? Where is the insert code?

Comment: @RaR. I've found the specified user using .findOne, and in the callback-function I've just typed user.files = {value: req.body.value, id: 123}. The db then saves each value seperately in an array like: ["req.body.value", "123"]

Comment: Can you try like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/23452838/6048928

Comment: Hmm, I don't know if that will work given that my id won't set. I found this: https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/mongoose-referencing-schema-in-properties-and-arrays/, where you create two schemas instead and link them together, gonna try that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply need to create a separate model for File and connect it to your User model using the 'ref' keyword :

```
let fileSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id     : Number,
    value    : String
});

let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    pass: { type: String, required: true },
    files: [{ type: Number, ref: 'File' }]
});

let User  = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
let File  = mongoose.model('File', fileSchema);

let f1 = new File({ _id: 1, value: 'File 1'});
let f2 = new File({ _id: 2, value: 'File 2'});
let f3 = new File({ _id: 3, value: 'File 3'});

let user1 = new User({user:'chuck', pass:'norris'});
user1.files.push(f1);
user1.files.push(f2);
user1.files.push(f3);

user1.save(function(err){  });
```

Now to get the data back:

```
User
.findOne({ user: 'chuck' })
.populate('files') // only works if we pushed refs to children
.exec(function (err, user) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log(user);
  //you can now loop through user.files and compare _id
  user.files.forEach(function(file) {
      if (file._id === req.params.id) {
         response.render("../home", file.value)
      }
   }
});
```

You can read about mongoose reference population here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Thank you, I did just that right before you answered, and now it works perfectly. Better design too :)