# Mongoose error Cannot read property 'baseCasterConstructor' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am getting this error when trying to push an object to an array of sub-documents.

This is my model:

```
let imagemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    titulo: String,
    descricao: String,
    arquivo: String
  })

let imovelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
  imagens: [imagemSchema]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Imovel', imovelSchema)
```

When I try to find an Imovel object and push an Imagem to it's imagens property, I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'baseCasterConstructor' of undefined

I'm starting to think that this can be an issue with mongoose itself.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please add code how you try to find and push object

Comment: let findImovel = imovelModel.findById(req.params.id).exec()
    findImovel.then(imovel => {
      try {
      let imagem = req.body
      let arquivo = req.file.filename
      imagem.arquivo = arquivo

      imovel.imagens.push(imagem)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!
The problem is related to the way I was trying to push the object to the children array.

This post [pushing object into array schema in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621970/pushing-object-into-array-schema-in-mongoose) 
helped me to solve changing the way I was trying to push from

```
   let findImovel = imovelModel.findById(req.params.id).exec() 
    findImovel.then(imovel => { 
    let imagem = req.body 
    let arquivo = req.file.filename 
    imagem.arquivo = arquivo 
    imovel.imagens.push(imagem)
```

To

```
let imagem = req.body
    let arquivo = req.file.filename
    imagem.arquivo = arquivo

    imovelModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, 
      {$push: {'imagens' : imagem}},
      {safe: true, upsert: true}).then(() => {
        return res.send()
      })
```

And it worked as I was expecting