# Node.JS & Mongoose - insert item into an array in the database

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently working on a project and I am stuck with inserting an item into an array/object in the database. What I am trying to do is to add the id of a 'upvoted' post to an array/list in the 'User' Collection, however, I cannot seem to get it to work.

The code for my schemas is as follows:

```
// this is a child scheme/sub-document
var uvpSchema = new Schema();
uvpSchema.add({
  post: String
});

var dvpSchema = new Schema();
dvpSchema.add({
  post: String
 });

//main schema
var userSchema = new Schema({
    firstname: { type: String, required: true },
    lastname: { type: String, required: true },
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    upVotedPosts: [uvpSchema],
    downVotedPosts: [dvpSchema],
    created_at: Date,
});
```

And here is the code in my 'routes.js' to insert the id of the post into the array:

```
var newPush = {
        post: postID  // postID is a variable that I have already defined
    };
    User.findOneAndUpdate({username: req.session.user}, {$push: {upVotedPosts: newPush}}, {upsert: true, save: true}, (err, user) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        user.upVotedPosts.push(newPush);
        User.save;
        res.redirect(req.get('referer'));
        console.log(user.upVotedPosts);
    });
```

The error I receive in my terminal is:

```
{ _id: 595f68b5fadd49105813f8a4 },{ _id: 595f693d3c2c21189004b0a7 },{ _id: 595f70a2df80e0252894551b }
events.js:163
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
```

Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: Why are you doing `uvpSchema.add`, why not just create the schema directly like `new Schema({post: String})`?

Comment: Also what isn't working? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Sorry about that: updated with more info about the error. I have tried both 'uvpSchema.add' and 'new Schema {...}' but they both return the same error

Comment: Hm that error is not very informative. Is there nothing else?

Comment: No, that's the only error I seem to get. It appears that the id of the item is being added to the array but not the item itself :/

Comment: What happens if you create the schema directly (i.e. without `uvpSchema.add`) like in my first comment?

Comment: The same error happens

Answer (score 0):

Route.js

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({username: req.session.user}, {$push: {upVotedPosts: newPush}}, {upsert: true, save: true}, (err, user) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    user.upVotedPosts.push(newPush);
    User.save;
    res.redirect(req.get('referer'));
    console.log(user.upVotedPosts);
});
```

You dont need to explicitly push, since you pushed using findOneandUpdate - $push

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621970/pushing-object-into-array-schema-in-mongoose)

Secondly , its

```
user.save()
```

and not

```
User.save
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :-)
Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Try to just redirect inside callback, remove user.upvoted.push and user.save

Comment: make sure you are restarting server after every change

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd like to thank everyone's' help ;-)

---

I finally managed to get it *partially* working! My problem was that my functions were running asynchronously, causing some problems. I solved this by adding callback functions to each mongoose function.

However, the same error is still being returned, causing the server to crash. Everything else works; the new item is added to the array.

Is there anyway to ignore the error so that the server doesn't crash?