# Rewrite mongoose code to avoid Versioning error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I think I'm coming up against this problem https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1844 .

I can see how that would happen - one request comes in, and tests is being updated, and at the same time another request comes, causing another update for tests.

I have schema that look like this

```
const User = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: { type: String, default: uuid.v1 },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  tests: [Test],
});


const Test = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    _id: { type: String, default: uuid.v1 },
    responses: [Response]
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);

const Response = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: { type: String, default: uuid.v1 },
  answer: {
    type: String,
    enum: [
      "StronglyAgree",
      "Agree",
      "SomewhatAgree",
      "Neutral",
      "SomewhatDisagree",
      "Disagree",
      "StronglyDisagree"
    ]
  },
  question: { type: String, ref: "Question" }
});

const Question = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: { type: String, default: uuid.v1 },
  description: String,
});
```

I have a class, `UserModel` that uses mongoose's models.

It does this

```
async createTest(userId) {
    try {
      const test = await this.testModel.create();
      try {
        const user = await this.model.findOne({ userId });
        if (user) {
          user.tests.push(test);
          return await user.save();
        } else {
          throw new Error("Non existent UserId");
        }
      } catch (e) {
        throw e;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

and this is what create looks like.

```
 async create() {
    if (!this._model) {
      await this._getModel();
    }
    try {
      const questions = await this.questionModel.getAllQuestions();
      const test = new this.model();
      questions.forEach(question => {
        const response = this.responseModel.create(question.id);
        test.responses.push(response);
      });
      await this.model.populate(test, {
        path: "responses.question",
        model: "Question"
      });
      return test;
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

I'm not sure how to re-write this to avoid the versioning problem (and I'd rather not skip versioning). The schema also makes sense to me as I don't want to carry duplicate descriptions of Questions (I might have to change the descriptions in future).

How can I do this?

Comment: You keep posting variations on the same thing. You were actually told that constructing a method like this "on the instance" that does not actually return a promise or callback is just wrong. For the general issue of adding items to an array, you should instead be using [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) as also described on [pushing object into array schema in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23452838/2313887)

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you - what piece of code are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

The only way is that you disable the versioning by putting

{
   "versionKey":false
}

at end of your schema.