# Inserting into array error in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my MongoDB schema, Seems like push operator is not working

```
locationCoordinate : {
    type : [Number],
    index: '2d'
},
```

i am getting Post data from frontend in my Node.js server which is having Longitude and Latitude

```
var event  = new Events({})
 (Events is the name of Schema )
```

I want to push into this array,
so this seems not to be working

```
Error on this line 
       event.locationCoordinate.push(req.body.longitude);
       event.locationCoordinate.push(req.body.latitude);
```

And then saving this by

```
event.save(function(err,result)){

}
```

The result may be something like
locationCoordinate[1,2]

Comment: Are using mongoose and mongoose models?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pushing object into array schema in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621970/pushing-object-into-array-schema-in-mongoose)

Comment: Mongoose Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var array = [];

array.push({"lng":req.body.longitude},{"lat":req.body.latitude}); // or
array.push(req.body.longitude,req.body.latitude); //just try mybe work
var Evnt = new Events()
               Evnt.type = array;
               Evnt.index = req.body.index;
Evnt.save(function(...){ ... });
```