# How to push into Array type entry

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to push variables into an `Array` type in one of my `Mongoose` model.

```
var CompetitionSchema = new Schema({
  joined_users:{type: Array, default:[]}
});
```

I need to append several users into this `Array`

I have a the following route:

```
//Add User to competition
router.post('/c/:competId/user', (req, res) => {
  query = {_id : req.params.competId}
  Competition.update(query, {"joined_users" : req.body.userId}).exec((err, compet)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    if(!compet){
      res.json({success: false, message:'Could not find compet'});
    }else if(compet){
      res.json({success: true, message:'All good!'})
    }
  })
});
```

But of course it replaces every time the first element of the Array. I couldn't find the proper function to append each `user` into `joined_users`.

Answer (score 1):

By default, mongoose will use `$set` if nothing is specified, and that's why your whole array gets replaced.

What you need is `$push`.

Try using the following:

```
Competition.update(query, {$push:{"joined_users" : req.body.userId}})
```

Comment: The second one should work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23452838/6048928